# Proof that the series for the generating function of the partition function converges?

Tags: number-theory, power-series, generating-functions, integer-partitions, infinite-product

For $|q| < 1$, the generating function of the partition function $p(n)$ is given by
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n) q^n
  = \prod_{k=1}^\infty {1 \over 1-q^k}. \tag{1}
$$
I have an intuitive understanding of this, but how do you know that the LHS converges?

---

Here's what I do know:

The RHS converges absolutely for $|q| < 1$ because its convergence is equivalent to that of
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log {1 \over 1-q^k}
  = \sum_{k=1}^\infty O(q^k).
$$
We can compare this to the partial products, since they relate to partitions in a known way, i.e. they cover all partitions where all parts are $\leq m$. So we have
$$
\left| \prod_{k=1}^\infty {1 \over 1-q^k} - \prod_{k=1}^m{1 \over 1-q^k}  \right|
  = \left| \prod_{k=m+1}^\infty p_m^*(n)q^k \right|,
$$
where $p_m^*(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ where at least one part is $>m$. Clearly
$$
\prod_{k=m+1}^\infty p_m^*(n)|q|^k
  \leq \prod_{k=m+1}^\infty p(n)|q|^k,
$$
as long as the RHS makes sense. Letting $m \to \infty$ will complete the proof, since this last RHS tends to $0$ as long as the LHS of (1) converges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of Andrews' book *The Theory of Partitions*. Of course in hindsight, it seems easy.

The sequence of partial sums
$$
S_N = \sum_{n=0}^N p(n) |q|^n
$$
is clearly increasing, and we'll show that it's also bounded. We have
$$
S_N \leq \prod_{k=1}^N {1 \over 1-|q|^k}
$$
because the LHS covers all partitions of all numbers $\leq N$ while the RHS covers all partitions where all the parts are $\leq N$, which clearly includes the former. Furthermore,
$$
\prod_{k=1}^N {1 \over 1-|q|^k}
  \leq \prod_{k=1}^\infty {1 \over 1-|q|^k}
$$
because all the factors are $\geq 1$. As shown in my original post, this converges, so we're done.