# Natural Boundary of Euler's Partition Generating Function

Tags: complex-analysis, integer-partitions, analytic-continuation

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$. Let's consider the analytic function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ given by, for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$,
$$f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-z^n)^{-1}.$$
For each positive integer $n$, let $p(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into positive integers.
Then, for $z\in\mathbb{D}$, $f$ admits the power series expansion
$$f(z)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(n)z^n.$$
By the monotone convergence theorem,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(n) \left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{k\to\infty} p(n) \left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(n) =\infty.$$
Therefore, $f$ cannot be analytically continued to the point $1$. It is well-known (*but rarely proved*) that

> the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$ is a natural boundary for $f$.

Actually, come to think of it, I haven't even found a proof of this fact. I would very much appreciate a reference or a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Remmert, Funktionentheorie 2 / Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory, Chapter 11 there is a

**Theorem by Gábor Szegő.** Let $f=\sum a_n z^n$ a power series such that there are only finite many different values for the coefficients. Then either $\mathbb{D}$ is the natural boundary for $f$ or $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{z^N-1}$ with a polynomial $p\in\mathbb{C}[z]$.

The second case $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{z^N-1}$ just states that the sequence $(a_n)$ is periodic for large $n$.

For the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) we have the formula
$$\phi(z) =\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-z^n) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n z^{(3n^2-n)/2}
$$

The sum has only the coefficients $\{0,\pm 1\}$ and the sequence of coefficients isn't periodic. Therefore, $\mathbb{D}$ is the natural boundary of $\phi(z)$.

Comment: When you expressed $\phi(z)$ as an infinite sum, you did not express it as a power series.

Comment: Certainly the infinite sum is a power series, because $(3n^2 -n)/2\in\mathbb{N}$. Only the numbering is unusual.

Comment: True, I should have looked at this after my morning coffee. Can you edit the post so that I can remove the down-vote? Perhaps add a brief argument that $f$ is irrational (i.e. the coefficients aren't periodic).

Answer (score 0):

Use the asymptotic formula $$p(n) \sim \frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}n}\exp\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt{n}\right)$$

in conjuction with the root test

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{p(n)|z|^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|z|}{\sqrt[n]{4\sqrt{3}n}}\exp\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = |z| < 1$$

Comment: You've put the cart before the horse, and you haven't answered my question. Firstly, you've used a deep result to prove what can be proved with much less (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662372/proof-that-the-series-for-the-generating-function-of-the-partition-function-conv?rq=1). Secondly, determining the radius of convergence of a power series is not the same thing as determining its (possible) natural boundary. Sometimes power series can be analytically continued beyond their radius of convergence.

Comment: @eloiprime alright consider a different approach. $\frac{1}{f}$ has zeros at every root of unity for all $n$, which are not isolated zeros given the density of the roots of unity on the unit circle.

Comment: How do we make this heuristic rigorous?

Comment: @eloiprime it is not a heuristic. $f$ has singularities at every point on a dense subset of $|z|=1$. It is not analytically continuable - this is a literal wall.

Comment: I agree with the following logical implication: if $f$ has a singularity at every root of unity, then the unit circle is a natural boundary for $f$. The heuristic part of your argument is when you argued that $f$ has a singularity at every root of unity! Sure, the $n$-th factor of the product has a singularity at every $n$-th root of unity. But, does that mean that $f$ also has a singularity at these points?

Comment: @eloiprime of course it does, from looking at $1/f$. For all $m>n$, the $m$th partial product is exactly $0$ at the $n$th roots of unity. If you are not defining an infinite product as the limit of a partial product, then you aren't doing math (mostly this comes from a frustration of dealing with another user that wants to claim that .0000....1 is a number)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132897/discussion-between-eloiprime-and-ninad-munshi).