# Finding a closed set in [0,1] that contains no open sets and is not a Lebesgue null set

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-measure

The task: 
Let $ 0 < \alpha < 1 $ 
Show there exists a closed set $ A \subset [0,1] $ that contains no non empty open sets and $\lambda(A) = \alpha$ (where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure).

My intuition: 
Intuitively, I can’t see how this would be, because for the Lebesgue measure to not be 0, it must (according to my understanding) contain some sort of intervals. However, if it contains an interval say $[a,b]$ then you should always be able to find an open set in the interval as simple as $(a,b)$.

Approaches I have considered:

- I thought I could construct $\mathbf{R}\backslash\mathbf{Q}$ and somehow find intervals because then there could not be any open sets.
- Maybe if I created some increasing sequence $A_n$ of sets then I could use that $$lim_{n\to\infty}\cup A_n = lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$$
- Or perhaps a sequence of disjoint intervals, so I can use the additivity of the measure.
- Maybe I don’t even have to find a specific set, it’s existence would be sufficient

I would really appreciate some guidance to help me solve the problem

Comment: Positive measure sets need not contain intervals.

Comment: Have you seen the Cantor set? Perhaps it can be modified to suit your needs.

Comment: You may look up generalized Cantor sets to construct such an A.

Comment: Fat Cantor sets. There are many postings about them here in MSE. In this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4545203/121671) two such fat Cantor sets are constructed